# Minecraft 1.10.2 command block doesn't activate other command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to do some stuff with command blocks in 1.10.2 . But I have come to a problem. To make things more compact I have placed command blocks like a tower. The bottom command block checks for a pushed button in a location. The top ones are suppose to do what I need but they don't. Any ideas? By the way the testforblock command is correct.
[image]

Comment: Are all of them set to `Always active`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain command blocks have to be set as "Always active" (you just click the "Needs redstone") or apply redstone signal.