# 1.14.4 Testing for a play killing another player, then outputting a result

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a scoreboard name of KillLog with the playerKillCount criteria.

I want the system to detect when a player kills another player, which should add a value of 1 to the scoreboard. This system should then see that a player has killed another player, increase the world border by 10 blocks, and then reset the counter to 0 to reset the system, so it actively looks for another player to be killed again.

The system I have been fiddling with does absolutely nothing and I don't know why. I have removed redundancies, toggled the blocks to always on so they don't require redstone, watched hours of tutorials and I don't know where the problem is. Forgive me, I'm new and hope to make better stuff than this dumb system later on.

**I expect this first block to execute a check 20 times a second the playerKilled score and when it equals 1 I expect it to activate the chain of blocks after it.**
[image]

**I'm more than confident in believing this second block will add 10 to the world border, but despite the command attached to it being true, the border remains the same size.**
[image]

**This last block, I believe, should reset the score in playerKilled to 0, but similarly to the block before it, it doesn't activate despite conditions being met.**
[image]

My problem is I must be believing something incorrectly about my system, but my limited knowledge and density of depth of command blocks makes it difficult to identify the problem. I believe the repeating block isn't actually testing for what I think it's doing, and since testfor doesn't exist anymore I'm at a loss.

*Edited for clarity and previous suggestions updated with pictures.

Comment: So, what happens when you run the command blocks you provided?

Comment: Nothing. I expected the repeating block to recognize a player died, like it constantly checks the value to see if it changed. Then the chain conditionals should play out when the repeating blocks detects it as =1. Nothing changes though when I manually set my playerKilled=1 manually through another block, and a testing server when another player killed me did not do anything either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft 1.10.2 command block doesn't activate other command block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276831/minecraft-1-10-2-command-block-doesnt-activate-other-command-block)

Comment: I switched the chain blocks to always active, updated the score to 1 and the world border stayed the same again. I feel like I'm just not putting the pieces together properly and I'm missing something. Initially, I believed the last chain block was resetting the score to 0 nullifying the border change, but the score never changes, like the blocks never activate.

Comment: What's your question? I see no question mark and the commands you have should at least do something. That said, your commands are a mess. The first one: "`execute if entity @a[<arguments>] …`" …what? What should execute? You wrote no command that actually does anything. Then the second one, it starts with "`execute run`", which is completely useless.

Comment: You should be able to combine the first two commands like so: `execute if entity @a[scores={playerKilled=1..}] run worldborder add 10 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it. I figured it out.

**This Repeating command block needs to be connected to a comparator and that points into an impulse block that then adds 10 to the world border, then resets the system using a chain block.**
[image]

I just needed a solution to the testfor command being removed, that's all. It's sorta a duplicate of another question, but not exactly the same.